# finding NEXT Day using python conditionals

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I run the following code to get the next day in format year/month/day by conditional, but one gives desired output but with just a little change in code doesn't. I had taken the leap and non leap years in the nested if's wherever needed.

Here is the code that gives output:

```
y=int(input('Enter a year:'))
d=int(input('Enter a day:'))
m=int(input('Enter a month:'))
print('Present Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(d))
if m==2:
    if ((y%4==0 and y%100!=0) or y%400==0) and d<29:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(d+1))
    elif (y%100==0 and y%400!=0) and d<28:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(d+1))
    elif ((y%4==0 and y%100!=0) or y%400==0) and d==29:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(3)+':'+str(1))
    elif d==28:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(3)+':'+str(1))
elif m==1 or m==3 or m==5 or m==7 or m==8 or m==10:
    if d<31:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(d+1))
    elif d==31:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m+1)+':'+str(1))
elif m==4 or m==6 or m==9 or m==11:
    if d<30:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(d+1))
    elif d==30:
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(m+1)+':'+str(1))
elif m==12 and d==31:
    print('Next Day= '+str(y+1)+':'+str(1)+':'+str(1))
```

Here is the code that doesnt give output if **line 12** is replaced by this:

```
    elif (y%100==0 and y%400!=0) and d==28:               
        print('Next Day= '+str(y)+':'+str(3)+':'+str(1))
```

Can anyone explain the difference as to why this code 2 doesnt give the output as code 1?

O/P by code1:
Present day: 2019/2/28
Next day: 2019/3/1

O/P by code2:
Present day: 2019/2/28

Comment: What output _does_ it give, and for what input?

Comment: Also note that the `datetime` library is made for things like these. https://gist.github.com/pipeworks-asmith/2f4f3fcefa6d8149a3501f83ae9c8012

Answer (score 0):

As @Adam Smith mentioned in the comments, unless this is for a homework assignment you should not be doing this by hand and should use the `datetime` library instead.

But to answer your question, by changing that line you get no output because `(y%100==0 and y%400!=0) and d==28` is false when `y` is 2019. Thus none of your conditions match and the program ends.